# List Index Error - Combining list elements via index

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

`'Original String = 1234 A 56 78 90 B'`

```
def func_1(one_dict):
    global ends
    ends = []
    for x in original_string:
        if x in one_dict:
            ends.append(one_dict[x])
    return ends
```

The above returns:

```
['B', 'A']
```

My next function is supposed to then combine them into 1 string and get value from dictionary. I've tried this with/without the `str` in `mult_ends` with the same result.

```
def func_2(two_dict):
    global mult_ends
    mult_ends = str(ends[0] + ends[1])
    for key in mult_ends:
        if key in two_dict:
            return two_dict[key]
```

The results confuse me since I use pretty identical processes in other functions with no issue.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why would the list index be out of range when there is clearly a 0 and 1? I've also added `global ends` to func_2 and I still received the same error.

*** RESTRUCTURED FUNCTIONS INTO 1 ***

```
def func_1(one_dict):
    global ends
    ends = []
    for x in original_string:
        if x in one_dict:
            ends.append(one_dict[x])
    mult_ends = ends[0] + ends[1]
    for key in two_dict:
        if key in mult_ends:
            return ends_final_dict[key]
    return None
```

Now, it actually does what I want it to do and returns the correct dictionary key in the event log:

```
A B
```

However, it does not return when I try to insert it back into my GUI for the user and it still throws the `IndexError: list index out of range.`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that people can run to reproduce your problem. As it stands, your code will not run because we don't know what `ends` is, or what `one_dict` is when you call the functions. You might find it useful to do some [debugging](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) first. 
Step through your code in a [debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) and observe where its behavior diverges from your expectations, and what values your variables contain when the error is thrown. Please also include the _full_ stack trace. This tells us exactly where the error